# Infos about the <a> tag

Tags: html, warnings, aptana

I have upgraded Aptana to version 3. Since then, I get warnings like:

```
<a><span id="contacts" rel="#overlayTest">Contact</span></a>

Multiple markers at this line:  
- should discard unexpected <a>  
- should discard unexpected </a>
```

**A**. Is it illegal to put an "a" tag before a "div" or a "span"?
**EDIT :** I had the error because I put no href inside the a tag.

I also get warnings like:

```
<a class="pointer"><li class="spacing5px">Journal</li></a>

Multiple markers at this line:    
- should discard unexpected </a>
- missing <li>
- missing </a> before <li>
```

**B**. Am I blind or there is really something wrong here?

Btw, my page loads perfectly. Those are just warnings, but it bugs me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it illegal to put an "a" tag before a "div" or a "span"?

You cannot put a div inside an anchor until HTML 5 (and I wouldn't do so for a long time as it needs too much hackery for browsers to handle it).

You can't put a list item anywhere that you can put an anchor and vice versa. (So an anchor cannot be a child element of a list, and a list item cannot be a child element of an anchor). I'm not sure if HTML 5 will change this or not.

Also:

- An anchor without an href is not a good idea. It shouts of JavaScript dependency. (If it has a name, then it shouts of being time to upgrade and put an id on a more appropriate element instead).
- spacing5px is a not [a good class name](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/goodclassnames)

Comment: I'm sure I read that HTML5 allows anything within `<a>` as long as it's not another element that allows user interaction, such as a button or another link.  Obviously, `<a>` is not allowed as the child of a `<ul>` element.

Comment: Good breakdown of the html5 block level link improvements: http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate the tips at the end also! :)

Answer (score 1):

Anchors are inline elements, so they should go inside block level elements, including `li` and `div` elements. The `span` should be OK though.